# How to flip a QImage

Tags: c++, qt5, transformation, qimage

What is the right way to flip/mirror a QImage? The following snippet does not work.

```
 //allocate buffer
 BYTE* pRgb32Buffer = new BYTE[width*height* 4];
 //create paint device
 QImage img = QImage(pRgb32Buffer , width, height, getStride(width, pixelFormat), QImage::Format_RGB32);
 //do some drawing on image (works!) 
 QPainter painter(&img);
 painter.drawText(10, 50, QString("some text"));
 //mirrore image (doesn't mirror the orignal buffer!!!)
 img = img.mirrored(false,true);
 //doesn't work either
 //QImage mirrored = img.mirrored();
 //img = mirrored;
 //mirrored.detach();
```

Comment: intentionally do you have `pRgb32Buffer` and `pBuffer` ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by doesn't work?  QImage::mirrored() returns a copy of the original image.  Mirroring will not affect the data in pRgb32Buffer.  Apart from that I see no reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I want to manipulate data in "pRgb32Buffer" !

Comment: Have you tried another QImage? `QImage imgMirrored = img.mirrored(false, true);`

Answer (score 3):

A solution using [`QImage::mirrored()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#mirrored):

`memmove(pRgb32Buffer, img.mirrored().bits(),img.byteCount());`

Answer (score 2):

I have this working code to mirror a QPixmap onto an QImage.

```
QPixmap* source = //... Getting my pixmap form somewhere...
QImage target(QSize(source->width(), source->height()), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
QPainter painter(&target);
QTransform transf = painter.transform();
transf.scale(-1, 1);
painter.setTransform(transf);
painter.drawPixmap(-source->width(), 0, *source);
```

The `source` contains the mirrored pixmap after that code. You should be able to do the same with `QImage`and the `QPainter::drawImage` function as alternative.

Optionally you can save the file if you want (make sure you have the imageformats dll's or it won't write):

```
QImageWriter writer("c:\\theimage.tiff", "tiff");
writer.setCompression(1);
writer.write(target);
```